# Typescript shows an error inside condition (IF) block where should be no undefined value

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements, undefined

Got into a strange situation on a project. Here is an example where TS shows an error:

```js
type Fruit = {
  name: string;
};

const myFruits: Fruit[] = [{ name: "Apple" }, { name: "Banana" }];

let asyncFuncResult: string | undefined = "NewName";
const asyncFuncResultConst: string | undefined = "NewName";
let result;

// Why TS shows an issue here?
if (asyncFuncResult) {
  result = myFruits.map(
    (fruit): Fruit => {
      return {
        ...fruit,
        name: asyncFuncResult
      };
    }
  );
}
```

It says for line `name: asyncFuncResult` that:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

[image: Screenshot of issue example]

Here is the demo and ways I found to fix that:
[CodeSandBox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-let-condition-issue-pyljcg?file=/src/index.ts)

But I don't get why it shows an error. We don't get into condition block if the variable is undefined. So there is no way we assign undefined value to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is just pessimistic about control flow analysis (see [#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)).

The type of `asyncFuncResult` is `string` in the same scope where you checked the variable (inside the `if`).
But when you use it in the callback of the `map` operator it is used in another scope - and since it is a variable (i.e. `let`) it could be changed by some other code before the callback is executed, so typescript pessimistically assumes `string | undefined`

```js
if (asyncFuncResult) {
  const aString = asyncFuncResult; // type of asyncFuncResult = 'string'
  result = myFruits.map(
    (fruit): Fruit => {
      return {
        ...fruit,
        name: asyncFuncResult // type of asyncFuncResult = 'string' | undefined
      };
    }
  );
}
```

I'd recommend using a constant instead:

```js
let asyncFuncResult: string | undefined = "NewName";
const asyncFuncResultConst = asyncFuncResult;

if (asyncFuncResultConst) {
  const aString = asyncFuncResultConst;
  result = myFruits.map(
    (fruit): Fruit => {
      return {
        ...fruit,
        name: asyncFuncResultConst
      };
    }
  );
}
```

The non-null assertion operator (`!`) would also work, but I try to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: `pessimistic about control flow analysis` — that is what I was thinking about. I haven't seen the issue and discussion.
So looks like the code in general is correct. The issue is the result of how TS "thinks" about it.

Comment: Right. I'd say, that the typechecking is currently just not smart enough to understand this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Fruit = {
  name: string;
};
```

In the code provided, the data type of **name** in **Fruit** is explicitly set to *string*. Consequently, the map function expects a return value with name as a *string* type, not *undefined*. Attempting to assign an *undefined* value without explicitly indicating it in the code will result in an error.

if you wish to assign an *undefined* value, you should do so explicitly in the code, as shown below:

```
type Fruit = {
  name: string | undefined;
};
```

You can also suppress the warning by simply using an **non-null assertion** operator in the code like below.

```
type Fruit = {
  name: string;
};

const myFruits: Fruit[] = [{ name: "Apple" }, { name: "Banana" }];

let asyncFuncResult: string | undefined = "NewName";
const asyncFuncResultConst: string | undefined = "NewName";
let result;

// Why TS shows an issue here?
if (asyncFuncResult) {
  result = myFruits.map(
    (fruit): Fruit => {
      return {
        ...fruit,
        name: asyncFuncResult! // Add a non-null assertion operator
      };
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get. There is no way in the code that undefined value will be assigned because we do the check first `if (asyncFuncResult)`. And TS doesn't show an error if this variable is a const.